# Showing a map is well defined

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

**Problem:** Let $A$ be any $\Bbb{Z}$-module, let $a$ be any element of $A$ and let $n\in \Bbb{Z}^+$. Prove that the map $\psi_a:\Bbb{Z/nZ}\to A$ given by $\psi_a(\overline{k})=ka$ is a well-defined $\Bbb{Z}$-module homomorphism if and only if $na=0$.

**Attempt:** Suppose $\psi_a$ is a well-defined $\Bbb{Z}$-module homomorphism.
Let $\psi_a(\overline{x}+n\overline{y})=\psi_a(\overline{x}+n\overline{z})$, where, $\overline{z}\neq \overline{y}$.
Therefore $$\psi_a(\overline{x})+n\psi_a(\overline{y})=\psi_a(\overline{x})+n\psi_a(\overline{z})$$ $(\because \psi_a$ is a $\Bbb{Z}$-module homomorphism).
$$xa+nay=xa+naz$$

Only possible if $na=0$.

Am i on right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Module homomorphisms maps $0$ to $0$. Thus, if $\psi_a$ is well-defined, $0_A = \psi_a(\overline{0}) = \psi_a(\overline{n}) = na$.
- If $na=0_A$, then for any $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb Z$ the following holds: $k_1 \equiv k_2 \!\pmod{n}$ *implies that* $k_1-k_2 = kn$ for some $k \in \mathbb Z$, and then $$\psi_a(\overline{k_1})-\psi_a(\overline{k_2}) = k_1a-k_2a = kna = k0_A = 0_A$$ which means: $\overline{k_1}=\overline{k_2}$ *implies that* $\psi_a(\overline{k_1})=\psi_a(\overline{k_2})$.

Comment: How "if $na=0_A$, then $k_1\equiv k_2(\text{mod} n)$"? Also please give a comment on my **attempt**.

Comment: I eddited my answer. Also, your attempt is fine, but you need to conclude: $xa+nya=xa+nza$ implies that $n(y-z)a = nya-nza = 0_A$, and then you can take $y=2$ and $z=1$.